# Get a ByteArray from BitmapData in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, bitmapdata

I would like to get a ByteArray from a BitmapData in AS3. I tried the following:

```
var ba:ByteArray = myBitmapData.getPixels(0,0);
```

It didn't work and I got this error `ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on flash.display::BitmapData/getPixels(). Expected 1, got 2.`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adobe said about [`BitmapData.getPixels`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixels%28%29) : "*Generates a byte array from a rectangular region of pixel data...*", so your parameter should be a [`Rectangle` object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html).

Take this example from Adobe.com :

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(80, 40, true);
var seed:int = int(Math.random() * int.MAX_VALUE);
bmd.noise(seed);

var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height);
var pixels:ByteArray = bmd.getPixels(bounds);
```

Comment: I tried it but I'm receiving this error after creating the ByteArray: `Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.
at flash.utils::ByteArray/readUnsignedByte()` Any ideas where it comes from?

Comment: I traced `pixels` and it's just a few hundred characters of `ÿ` - so I guess it's empty or corrupt?

Comment: @Tom No you can't understand anything because it's a ByteArray. I meant put your ActionScript code in your original question text to see why you got that error.

Comment: @Tom regarding `it's just a few hundred characters of ÿ` well thats because of the way you're tracing. `ÿ` is the **UTF** (text) version of the **Hex** value `FF`.. I think you got a lot of white pixels in your image?? To trace those bytes properly use `pixels.toString(16)`. There is no automatic "zero padding" in Flash  so bytes like `00 00 0F 0A BB` will look like `F0ABB`which is misleading unless you **[write your own function](http://paazmaya.com/reading-and-writing-hex-formatted-data-from-and-to-bytearray)**, but thats for later on..

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the other answer, `getpixels` expects a `.rect` meaning rectangular area of some displayObject (like Sprite, MovieClip, Shape or other already exisiting BitmapData.

`getPixels(). Expected 1, got 2.` is becuase it should have been:

`var ba:ByteArray = myBitmapData.getPixels( myBitmapData.rect);`

Study this code and see if it helps you :

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray;

var picBMP:Bitmap; var picBMD:BitmapData; 
var pic_canvas:Sprite = new Sprite(); //container for image

var loader:Loader = new Loader(); //image loader

loader.load(new URLRequest("pic1.jpg")); //load some JPG/PNG/GIF/SWF
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, img_load_Complete);

function img_load_Complete(evt:Event):void
{
    picBMP = loader.content as Bitmap;
    pic_canvas.addChild(picBMP);

    stage.addChild(pic_canvas); //container now added to stage (screen)

    BMP_toBytes(); //do function to convert to bytes
}

function BMP_toBytes():void
{
    var PC = pic_canvas; //shortcut reference to pic_canvas (less typing)

    picBMD = new BitmapData(PC.width, PC.height, true, 0xFFFFFF);
    picBMD.draw(PC); //make bitmapdata snapshot of container

    ba = picBMD.getPixels(picBMD.rect);
    trace("BA length : " + ba.length); //check how many bytes in there

    ba.position = 0; //reset position to avoid "End of File error"

    bytes_toPixels(); //do function for bytes as pixels to some new container
}


function bytes_toPixels():void
{
    var new_BMP:Bitmap = new Bitmap; var new_BMD:BitmapData; 
    var new_canvas:Sprite = new Sprite(); //another new container for pixels

    ba.position = 0; //reset position to avoid "End of File error"

    //we can reuse picBMD W/H sizes since we have copy of same pixels
    new_BMD = new BitmapData(picBMD.width, picBMD.height, true, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    new_BMD.setPixels(new_BMD.rect, ba); //paste from BA bytes
    new_BMP.bitmapData = new_BMD; //update Bitmap to hold new data

    new_canvas.x = 150; new_canvas.y = 0; new_canvas.addChild(new_BMP);
    stage.addChild(new_canvas); //add to screen
}
```

Hope it helps..