# Security Error when trying to load ByteArray from mediaPromise

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

in a mobile application i need to send an image which the user either took with the camera or picked from a cameraroll.
I am using the starling framework and feathersUI ( although i think this does not matter to problem )
When the mediapromise is loaded using loadFilePromise i use the following code to deal with the image data:

```
_mediaLoader = new Loader()
//loading the filePromise from CameraRoll
_mediaLoader.loadFilePromise(_mediaPromise);
_mediaLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.COMPLETE, onLoadImageComplete);
private function onLoadImageComplete(event:flash.events.Event=null):void {
    //creating the starling texture to display the image inside the application
    var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmapData(Bitmap(_mediaLoader.content).bitmapData, false, false, 1);
    //now trying to load the content into a bytearray to send to the server later
    var bytes:ByteArray=_mediaLoader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes;
}
```

the last line of code results in a Security error:
Error #2044: Unhandled SecurityErrorEvent:. text=Error #2121: Security sandbox violation: app:/myapp.swf: http://adobe.com/apollo/[[DYNAMIC]]/1 cannot access . This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.

I tried

```
Security.allowDomain("*")
```

as a test
but then i get:
SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.

As a workaround i write my own png ByteArray inside the Application from the loaders BitmapData using Adobes PNGEncoder Class:

```
var ba:ByteArray=PNGEncoder.encode(Bitmap(_mediaLoader.content).bitmapData)
```

But this takes a significant amount of time ...

I also tried the FileReference to load the image but

```
_mediaPromise.file
```

and

```
_mediaPromise.relativePath
```

are both null.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a known problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: As I have no real answere to this yet, I can tell you that I solved that problem in my last project by using com.freshplanet.ane.AirImagePicker where the returned Data is of type BitmapData. So if you are stuck with your code and there is no way out, have a look at this ANE, it worked for me. Are you currently requesting the native Camera App manually or what route are you currently going?

Comment: Getting the BitmapData is no Problem using Bitmap(_mediaLoader.content).bitmapData
Getting the raw ByteArray is the issue ...

Comment: Have you tried receiving the ByteArray from the BitmapData with getPixels? (see [this SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444583/get-a-bytearray-from-bitmapdata-in-as3))

Comment: Yes, i did. But that generates a huge file ... which needs to be converted to png/jpg, which can take quite a significant amount of ram/time on mobile. especially with 6MP and up Images ...

Comment: Well, that stuff has to be processed somehow. You said you are using the Adobe PNGEncoder and that it takes to much time to encode. I solved those problem by using Lee Burrows AsyncEncoder Class that you can find [here](https://github.com/LeeBurrows/Async-Image-Encoders). It supports several Image Filetypes and can encode your data asynchronous to your runtime. There is no way getting around encoding time, but this SWC makes it a breeze. This is the only idea left I can give you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but the ByteArray in the MediaPromise is already a png / jpg, since it is the Data that the OS provides. No re-encoding neccessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have found a solution based on a post about the processing of exif data mentioned here: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/10/parsing-exif-data-from-images-on-mobile-devices.html

the crucial code

```
private function handleMedia(event:MediaEvent):void{

    _mediaPromise=event.data as MediaPromise;
    _imageBytes=new ByteArray()
    var mediaDispatcher:IEventDispatcher = _mediaPromise.open() as IEventDispatcher;
    mediaDispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onMediaPromiseProgress);
    mediaDispatcher.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, onMediaPromiseComplete);
};
private function onMediaPromiseProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void{
    var input:IDataInput = e.target as IDataInput;
    input.readBytes(_imageBytes, _imageBytes.length, input.bytesAvailable);
};
private function onMediaPromiseComplete(e:flash.events.Event):void{
    _mediaLoader = new Loader();
    _mediaLoader.loadBytes(_imageBytes)

};
```

works like a charm for me on ipad and iphone.